# How to use grep in a function?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to write a program in C to search for a word in some file 
May you help me please ?

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int pid;
    //string s;
    //s = grep();
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0)
    {
       printf("Failed");
       exit(-1);
    }

    else if ( pid == 0)
    {
       printf("Child id %d\n",getpid());
       execlp("/bin/bzexe","grep the", NULL);
    }

    else 
    {
       wait(NULL);
       printf("Parent id %d |\n ",getpid());
       exit(0);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `execlp`, the arguments to the command must be separate arguments to the function. So it should be:

```
execlp("/bin/bzexe", "grep", "the", (char*)NULL);
```

You should also cast the `NULL` argument to `(char*)`, because the `NULL` macro doesn't necessarily expand to a pointer type, and varargs functions like `execlp` don't automatically convert to pointer types.

Comment: It didn't work . It just gave me the Child ID & Parent ID .

Comment: Since you didn't give a filename argument to `grep`, it will process standard input. If you redirect your program's input to a file, it will show all the lines matching `the`.

Comment: How I can give a filename argument to grep ?

Comment: It's the second argument to the program. Just like on the command line: `grep pattern filename`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to search for a word in some file using exec() system call then you can do it by using this command below:

```
 execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", "grep word filename.extension", (char *) NULL);
```

For example, to search for the letter "a" in q1.cpp you can use this command:

```
execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", "grep a q1.cpp", (char *) NULL);
```

You can run multiple commands in one argument in the case of "-c".

If you want to do the same task with execl() then you can do it by using the command given below:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "grep word filename.extension", (char *) NULL);
```

Comment: Why invoke a shell? They can call `grep` directly.

Comment: @JohnKugelman can you please mention that method? because I think that if you want to execute shell commands in C/C++ code then you have to use exec() system call. The method I had mentioned works fine. You can't call grep command without using exec() system call in C/C++.

Comment: Drop `bash -c` and `sh -c`, I mean. As in `execlp("grep", "grep", "word", "filename.extension", (char *) NULL)`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes, you're right that also works fine but the one I had mentioned is also fine. Moreover, in case if we want to search a word in all the files of a directory then the one you had mention will work but through some warning for e.g. `execlp("grep", "grep", "word", "*.*", (char *) NULL)` will give us grep: *.*: No such file or directory and then output(correct). However, if we use `execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", "grep word *.*", (char *) NULL);` it will work fine.So basically I wanted to write a generic one.